# Karaf 2.3.2 spring core dependency (spring feature) not found

Tags: apache-karaf

The issue is that karaf 2.3.2 tries to download "org.springframework.core" artifact but fails, it should download "spring-core" artifact as karaf 2.2.7 does. 
In maven repo only "spring-core" exist (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-core/). Any ideas why Karaf 2.3.2 has unexisted "org.springframework.core" dependency instead of existing "spring-core" dependency? Maybe another repository (not maven standard) should be used?
The version is written here:http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/assemblies/features/standard/2.3.2/standard-2.3.2-features.xml

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix that here (add spring repo):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-2430